# Making a turtle stop and then go after a special event - Robotic lawn mower simulation project

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to simulate a robotic lawn mower on Netlogo. My first goal was it finds its way home to recharge itself when the battery is low.

This is now done (thanks Luke !) but I can't figure how to make the lawnmower stop when it reaches the house (it keeps moving 2 patches around). Therefore my energy slider goes infinitely below zero.
I first thought of adding an event "recharge" and placing it after "check death" in *to go* with a  *if* instance. But :

- How do I say *if car goes on specific patch  : stop and get energy* ? Should I use a special patch color for the house and then code *if car goes on blue patch.....* ?
- Could adding the recharge event at the end of the *to go* elements would possibly create a conflict because recharge only goes when on low battery ? Would putting it in check death be a solution ?

Then I would like it to go back to work after instant recharge.

[image]

Any ideas ?

Here's the code :

```
breed [cars car]
cars-own [target]

breed [houses house]
to setup
  clear-all
  setup-patches
  setup-cars ;;represent lawn mower
  setup-house
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-patches
  ask patches [set pcolor green] ;; Setup grass patches
  ask patches with [
    pxcor = max-pxcor or
    pxcor = min-pxcor or
    pycor = max-pycor or
    pycor = min-pycor ] [
    set pcolor red ;; Setup the borders of the garden
  ]
end

to setup-cars
create-cars 1 [
    setxy 8 8
    set target one-of houses
  ]

end

to setup-house
  set-default-shape houses "house"
  ask patch 7 8 [sprout-houses 1]
end

to place-walls
  if mouse-down? [
    ask patch mouse-xcor mouse-ycor [ set pcolor red ]
    display
  ]
end


to go
  move-cars
  cut-grass
  check-death ;; Check % battery.
  tick
end

to move-cars
  ask cars
  [
    ifelse [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = red
      [ lt random-float 360 ]   ;; see red patch ahead turn left.
      [ fd 1 ]                  ;; otherwise it is ok to go.
    set energy energy - 1
]
  tick
end

to cut-grass
  ask cars [
    if pcolor = green [
      set pcolor gray
    ]
  ]
end

to check-death ;; when low energy lawn mower will go back to house
  ask cars [
    ifelse energy >= 150
    [ set label "Energy ok" ]
    [ set label "Low Energy, returning to base"
      set target min-one-of houses [distance myself]
      face target
      ifelse distance target < 1
      [ move-to target ]
      [ fd 1 ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a logical flag (eg `charging?`) in conjunction with a counter (eg `charge-time`) to do this. Try modifying your `cars-own` definitions like this:

```
cars-own [target charging? charge-time]
```

and `setup-cars` like this:

```
to setup-cars
  create-cars 1 [
    setxy 8 8
    set target one-of houses
    set charging? false
  ]  
end
```

Then you can have the mower do different things based on whether `charging?` is true or false. Try modifying your `move-cars` and `check-death` to accommodate these changes (side note- you've got a tick in both `go` and `move-cars`):

```
to move-cars
  ask cars [ 
    ifelse charging? [
      set charge-time charge-time + 1
      if charge-time > 14 [
        set energy 200
        set charging? false
        set charge-time 0
      ]
    ] [
      ifelse [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = red
      [ lt random-float 360 ]   ;; see red patch ahead turn left.
      [ fd 1 ]                  ;; otherwise it is ok to go.
      set energy energy - 1
    ]
  ]
end

to check-death ;; when low energy lawn mower will go back to house
  ask cars [
    ifelse energy >= 150
    [ set label "Energy ok" ]
    [ set label "Low Energy, returning to base"
      set target min-one-of houses [distance myself]
      face target
      ifelse distance target < 1
      [ move-to target 
        set charging? true
      ]
      [ fd 1 ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

I suggest you change `energy` a turtle variable like `car-energy` so that the turtles values are independent of your slider. That would mean you could have multiple mowers and they could reset their energy level to the slider setting once they are charged! You would just include a line like

`set car-energy energy`

in your `setup-cars` (and then modify so that `energy` in your car procedures is instead `car-energy`).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I am very happy with your help !

Everything works like a charm. But for your last advice, I keep getting  a "Nothing named ENERGY has been defined" error at the line  _set car-energy energy_ in _to setup-cars_ even after changing everything.

Do you know what's up ?

Comment: Sounds like you changed the `energy` slider on the interface to `car-energy`- sorry I should have clarified. You would leave that slider as is, and then also include a `cars-own` variable called `car-energy`. Does that make sense?

Comment: I got it ! Works like a charm. I tried to create a monitor counting  the car energy to read it but cant figure what to write in the _reporter_ case. `count car-energy` and `display car-energy` don't work.

Comment: Maybe try `[car-energy] of one-of cars`?