# How to make discrete event simulation for specific times with Netlogo

Tags: time, netlogo

I would like to program agents to have periods of activity and inactivity. For example, following a pattern of 4 seconds of activity (A) and 100ms of no activity (B).

[image: Figure]

I can not use only ticks to set these periods.
Is there any way to set agents to follow this pattern with the possibility to change the length of A and B from period to period?

Thank you.

Comment: have you looked at the time extension?

Comment: what does "I can not use only ticks to set these periods" mean? why not? ticks is how you measure simulated time in a NetLogo model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have any code that we could look, but based on my little knowledge, you could do something with a `waiting?` boolean like this :

```
    turtles-own [target waiting? waiting-time]

    ifelse waiting? [
      set waiting-time waiting-time + 1
      if waiting-time > 1 [ ;; Defined wait time here
        set waiting? false
        set waiting-time 0
      ]
```

I think you could do the same with the same syntax and a `working` boolean. With an `if working-time > 4 [ ]`.

I am just beggining with Netlogo so I hope my response is not too confused and that you understand what I mean.
Someone explained it perfectly to me in another post ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47014217/making-a-turtle-stop-and-then-go-after-a-special-event-robotic-lawn-mower-proj/47019565#47019565)). Maybe checking it will be more understandable.

Comment: Thank you. Ii seems that turtles will wait several ticks to leave the waiting state. I only have to figure out how to map ticks to 4 seconds and 100 miliseconds.

Comment: You might arbitrarily decide that one tick = 100 milliseconds, or whatever ratio you want.